# Enlarge ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot made in `R` with `ggplot2`
[image]

which is drawn by the following code:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_smooth(fill='grey', alpha=0.3, span=0.1, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color='AAA',linetype='AAA')) +
  geom_smooth(fill='grey', alpha=0.3, span=0.9, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color='BBB',linetype='BBB')) +
  scale_colour_manual(name='test', values=c('AAA'='chocolate', 'BBB'='yellow')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name='test', values=c('AAA'='dashed','BBB'='solid')) +
  theme_minimal() +theme(legend.position = "top")
```

**Problem:** from the legend, it is not easy to understand that the "AAA" line is dashed, since the box is too small.

How can I enlarge it?

I would love to have something similar to:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the legend themes you can change here http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
# create your legend guide
myguide <- guide_legend(keywidth = unit(3, "cm"))
# now create your graph
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_smooth(fill='grey', alpha=0.3, span=0.1, 
              aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color='AAA',linetype='AAA')) +
  geom_smooth(fill='grey', alpha=0.3, span=0.9, 
              aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color='BBB',linetype='BBB')) +
  scale_colour_manual(name='test', 
                      values=c('AAA'='chocolate', 'BBB'='yellow'),
                      guide = myguide) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name='test',  
                        values=c('AAA'='dashed','BBB'='solid'), 
                        guide = myguide) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "top")
```

See `?guide_legend` and [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html).

This will give you

[image]

You can use `keywidth` and `keyheight` to manipulate how much the key "stretches" into both directions. With `title.position`, `direction`, etc you can further finetune the legend.

Note that since you have multiple legends that are merged, you need to specify the guide to all merged scales. I simplified this by creating the guide outside as an object first.